# UnrecognizedPropertyException from jackson when reading data produced by jersey-json

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have this JAXB-annotated class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeClass {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String value;
}
```

Based on this class, a JSON document was produced using jersey-json (via `com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext`):

```
{
   "@value":"someValue"
}
```

Note that jersey decided to use `@value` as tag name (and not simply `value`), probably in order to honour the `@XmlAttribute` annotation.

Now the task is to read this json document using jackson-json and produce an instance of the JAXB annotated class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JaxbAnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
DeserializationConfig deserConfig = mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
mapper.setConfig(deserConfig);
SerializationConfig serConfig = mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);
mapper.setConfig(serConfig);
mapper.readValue(jsonFile, SomeClass.class);
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@value" (class test.jersey.vs.jackson.SomeClass), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "value"])
 at [Source: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\junit5080915042527904512\json.txt; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: test.jersey.vs.jackson.SomeClass["@value"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1093)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1477)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1455)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2740)
```

My question now is whether there is a way to tell jackson to associate the `@value` tag from the JSON document with the `value` field of the class.

I tried specifying a `PropertyNamingStrategy`, but that was never called during deserialization.

```
PropertyNamingStrategy pns = new PropertyNamingStrategy() {

    @Override
    public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedField field, String defaultName) {

        if (field.hasAnnotation(XmlAttribute.class)) {
            if (defaultName.startsWith("@")) {
                return defaultName.substring(1);
            }
        }
        return super.nameForField(config, field, defaultName);
    }

};

DeserializationConfig deserConfig = mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector).with(pns);
mapper.setConfig(deserConfig);
```